# For a random pile of cylindrical batteries, what is the probability of a short circuit?

Tags: geometry

The question is not really an engineering issue, even if it seems to be on the first sight. I'm not trying to solve a practical problem, I try to understand whether this can even handled as a well defined geometrical problem.

Imagine a large number of AA battery cells in a non conducting container.
They have been put into the container by dropping each of them in a random orientation at a random location. The batteries are cylindrical and have a cylindrical extension as "-" contact at one end. The other end is the "+" contact, except the edge.

I try to get at least an intuition of how probable it is that there is a short circuit in the the volume of batteries.
I think it could be simulated, but is it possible to calculate the probability otherwise?

A short circuit is possible with batteries touching "+" and "-" contacts in a flat circle.
I'm thinking about the geometric part of the question, so there is a further simplification needed: The friction. No friction at all would create a parallel packing, I think even an optimal packing. Perfect stickiness is also not a good simplification, because it would involve rolling of batteries or an extremely loose packing. Choose any friction simplification that possibly works. But at this point, it seems to be a question that depends more on physics than math.
Use any simplification that helps<sup>*</sup>.

A calculation is surely not practically possible for even a hand full of batteries, I'm not trying to solve a practical problem. But is it even possible to handle is as a well defined geometrical problem?

---

<sup>*</sup> Note that I do not even specify the length and radius of the battery cells. It would implicitly make it an engineering question, I think.

Comment: Are the contacts the open disks or the closed disks of the ends of the cylinders?  I did not understand what your comment about "except the edge" means.

Comment: @kimchilover I mean it is the open disk, otherwise there would be a huge number of connections by sequences of touching edges, for example a parallel sequence would be conducting. But it does not really make the problem less interesting, just different.

Comment: So contact can be made only if two batteries' ends are coplanar?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, but I do not insist on it, any simplification is fine, it is interesting with open or closed disk at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I took out some batteries from my drawer and I found out that I need a minimum of 9 AA batteries to form a loop (because of the nubby top part and ring of plastic around the bottom).

Assuming a 2D plane and 5 degrees of error.

5 degrees / 360 degrees = 0.014.

The first battery can be in any orientation.

The second battery has to be in one or two orientations.

The third battery on can only be in one orientation.

So 1 * 0.028 * 0.014^7 = 3 * 10^-15 which is a chance of one in 333 trillion.

Of course there are problems to this solution. It's possible to form a loop with more than 9 batteries, but the chance of that happening is magnitudes lower.

The five degrees of error is completely arbitrary, but a small degree of error makes sense because the minimum angle between two batteries is 140 degrees. If the angle was any bigger, then the loop won't close with 9 batteries.

Also, I only considered the rotation of the battery and not its position. If the position was accounted for, the chances of forming a loop would probably be lower.

Finally, I limited my solution to a 2D plane. In a 3D space, the chances of forming a loop would be much lower because there are simply more angles.